# php opencart website 500 status

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

after 2 years, Suddenly if I try to visit an https://www.xxxx.com website built with opencart I get 500 status error, however, when I load the website dashboard and I logon, then I go back to  https://www.xxxx.com  and it works, I **DO NOT** get the 500 error status. I have tried the steps above on different clients (chrome) and I get 500 status unless I logon to the dashboard. I checked mysql and apache all running ok, I restarted the digital ocean server (ubuntu 14.04) without luck.I found the following log in the apache error

```
call to a member function getModule() on a non-object in /var/www/html/catalog/controller/common/footer_modules.php on line 23
```

why suddenly I am getting this error? code not changed at all. I do not know how to troubleshoot it. I appreciate some detailed steps.

Comment: Possibilities include. 1. You got hacked. 2. Someone upgraded PHP. 3. Someone tried to upgrade opencart. 4. Systems do weird things when they run out of disk space sometimes but I doubt that's your situation.

Comment: thanks for the clues. Disk space usage on 59%. the weird thing is logging to the dashboard from one machine and then the website page loads fine. I guess I cannot correct the hacked files as I do not know which one.

Comment: Maybe useful? https://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-2-x-how-to-deal-with-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getmodule-error-after-activating-maintenance-mode.html

Comment: I will give it a shot and will report here. your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by going to dashboard's Settings --> Store -- > maintenance and unchecking maintenance to No. Maintenance tickbox was set to Yes. Somehow the error does not indicate at all the cause. I set it to No and the error disappeared. I am investigating now whether someone hacked the server or someone had access to the server.